# Traversing a Structure linked list of strings (C programming)

Tags: c, linked-list

If the structure in C is defined as

```
struct StringList{ char* value; struct StringList* next; };
```

I have to print from head the address of value for each element

so I have:

```
void print (struct StringList* head){ 

    struct StringList* sp = Head;
    while ((sp->next)->next != NULL){
        printf( "value: %d", &sp->value);    
    }
```

I posted on programmers exchange too not sure which site is more appropriate

Comment: What is your specific question? Is the code you've given not working? What error/issue are you getting?

Comment: Your while loop will go on forever. You are not updating your `sp` value!

Comment: The code will not also compile as there is no variable as `Head`(capital H) which you are using to initialize `sp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an extra `sp` variable. Also you are not updating it inside the while loop. Also

`(sp->next)->next!=NULL`

will crash if `sp->next` is NULL. I am showing a way by reusing your `head` variable.

```
void print (struct StringList* head){ 
    while (head != NULL){
        printf( "value: %p", &(head->value));    
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `%p` would be more appropriate for printing addresses of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You'll crash on an empty or one-element list.  Your loop condition should be changed, and you're printing a pointer so you need to use the correct format, and you were not updating `sp` in the loop body:

```
while (sp != NULL)
{
    //printf("Value: %d\n", sp->value);
    printf("Address: %p\n", (void *)&sp->value);
   sp = sp->next;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to print the addresses of the values, not the values.

Comment: Just asking: wouldn't `printf("Address: %p\n", sp->value);` work ? Is it needed/prefered to use `(void *)&sp->value` for some reason?

Comment: @chrk: The `%p` format is for printing a `void *`.  I learned to program C on a machine where the `char *` value for an address was different from the `AnythingElse *` value for the same memory location. In that environment, you learn to make sure that things are the right type.  You can get away with the sloppiness when the address type is `char *`, but you can't be certain with other pointer types.

Comment: Thanks would %d, &sp->value , not print the address too?

Comment: @user3543440: Not reliably or portably.  On a 64-bit machine, `%d` prints a 32-bit `int` and you would be passing a 64-bit `int *`.  It gets really bad when you have other conversion specifications after the `%d` because they probably treat the 32-bits of pointer that `%d` didn't print as the next data item.  Don't mess with it; play safe.  If you want an address in decimal, use `<inttypes.h>` and `uintptr_t` and `printf("Address: %" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&sp->value);`.